# Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 170): Unknown tag 'elif' in xyz for markdown code block

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I use `Jekyll` to create my static website. One of my markdown has the following code block

````
....
```yaml
# Example pillar 'packages' YAML
{% if grains['os'] == 'RedHat' %}
apache: httpd
git: git
{% elif grains['os'] == 'Debian' %}
apache: apache2
git: git-core
{% endif %}
` ` `
...
````

However the generation of the site fails with

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 170): Unknown tag 'elif' in
```

How would I properly escape such "code" that it is renderd properly and not interpreted as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% raw %}
... any liquid or liquid-like code will be displayed as is.
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: Thanks. The syntax above is correct cause the markdown shows `jinja` syntax from a salt pillar and in fact has nothing todo with liquid